# How to find out which files were copied in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: files, security, copy

I forgot to lock my machine and I suspect some confidential files were copied. How can I tell what was copied?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-atime` option to the `find` command (see `man find`[Online `man` page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/find.1.html)), and the `-u` and/or `--time=use` options to `ls` (see `man ls`[Online `man` page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/ls.1.html)).

Comment: all of the above says command not found. could you give an example please?

Comment: @WannabeJavaGeek it's possible with `man` is not installed (does `which man` really print nothing to console?), but almost impossible that `ls` isn't available. Check again, please. Did you realise that some of the highlighted words are arguments above?

Comment: `man` is only explaining. no examples and i am new in linux. an example would work here

Comment: I remember that the `-atime` switch only works when the underlying filesystem maintains that attribute which it doesn't by default for performance and other reasons (e.g. SSD wear out). Am I wrong?

Comment: @PerlDuck it depends on the filesystem in use, and how it's mounted. OP didn't even specify if it was SSD.

Comment: @PerlDuck yes you're right. By default ext4 partitions will be mounted with [`relatime`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_(system_call)#RELATIME) on Ubuntu (to save on writes). But I believe `find` will search on the atime that is recorded (see `stat`), so this sort of works, or looks like it does, it's just that the result won't be reliable as atime isn't updated on every access (only according to relatime rules)